# Razor Pages _Layout.cshtml, and strongly typed partial pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

There are a lot of similar questions, but no good answers. This is my attempt:

I want to use a partial view in _Layout.cshtml for a menu that will appear on every page.

My _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
    <partial name="_TopLevelMenu" model="Model.MainMenuModel" />
 </div>
```

My _TopLevelMenu.cshtml partial:

```
@model List<Data.Models.MainMenuModel>

<ul id="ulMainMenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
    
@foreach (var item in Model){
    <li @item.NavId>
      <a href="@item.NavigationUrl">@item.DisplayName</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

My error:

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'MyApp.Pages.IndexModel' does not contain a definition for 'MainMenuModel'
```

Things I've tried:

"[Pass the model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67184732/3845390)" - I get the same error when I do this, and besides, Visual Studio strongly advises me to use the Partial tag helper instead.

Use the `partial` tag without a named model, which gives me this error: `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'MyApp.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Data.Models.MainMenuModel]'.`

I tried it with just `MainMenuModel` but Visual Studio tells me it's a type and I can't use a type for my model.

I looked at [this website](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages) for guidance, and it unhelpfully uses some of my key search words ("menu", "layout") but doesn't use the _Layout.cshtml page as part of the example.

If I do `<partial name="_TopLevelMenu" model=new MainMenuModel()" />` I don't get errors but I also don't get my data from the partial to populate.

What must I do to properly have a partial be the menu items on all pages?

Comment: I'll update my site to include a bit more information of passing models to partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chen has provided a good explanation of the cause of your error message and a resolution, and also notes that when passing models to partials in a layout, you must define the model in *every* page that references the layout. You could do this by implementing a base class for your pages and define the model there, and then derive all your pages from the base class, but in practice, that can become very cumbersome to manage.

I recommend using View Components for segments of UI that go into layouts, where the UI segment depends on server-side logic for generating the content:

- https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0

They are a little more complicated to set up than a partial, but they are responsible for generating their own data.

Comment: I was going to post a less good answer than this as the answer - the answer is -"you can't, use view components instead - though you technically can use partials on the layout page, you have to include the model everywhere" which is less than optimal.

Comment: Of course, yours is the best answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your error message shows that you need to define a `MainMenuModel` property in `IndexModel`, like this:

IndexModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public List<MainMenuModel> MainMenuModel { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        MainMenuModel = new List<MainMenuModel>()
        {
            new MainMenuModel() { NavId = 1,NavigationUrl = "Url1", DisplayName = "Name1"},
            new MainMenuModel() { NavId = 2,NavigationUrl = "Url2", DisplayName = "Name2"},
            new MainMenuModel() { NavId = 3,NavigationUrl = "Url3", DisplayName = "Name3"},
        };
        return Page();
    }
}
```

_TopLevelMenu.cshtml:

```
@model List<Data.Models.MainMenuModel>

<ul id="ulMainMenu" class="nav navbar-nav">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li @item.NavId>
            <a href="@item.NavigationUrl">@item.DisplayName</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
    <partial name="_TopLevelMenu" model="Model.MainMenuModel" />
</div>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Please note that if you add this partial view in `Layout` for all pages, you should define the `MainMenuModel` property in each page. For example, in `PrivacyModel`:

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    public List<MainMenuModel> MainMenuModel { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        MainMenuModel = new List<MainMenuModel>()
        {
            new MainMenuModel() { NavId = 1,NavigationUrl = "Url1", DisplayName = "Name1"},
            new MainMenuModel() { NavId = 2,NavigationUrl = "Url2", DisplayName = "Name2"},
            new MainMenuModel() { NavId = 3,NavigationUrl = "Url3", DisplayName = "Name3"},
        };
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]